# Can't create the sum of two values (2+2 isn*t 4 but 22)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

sorry if this is a noob question, but well, I'm a noob.
I want to get the sum of the values of several text field into another text field. My code looks like this:

```
$('.button').mouseup(function()  {
    var sum = $("#field1").val()+$("#field2").val();
    $("#result").val(sum);
});
```

When I click the button the sum of 3+3 isn't 6 but 33. It just adds all numbers to the textfield. If I change the "+" into a "*" it works, 3*3 is 9. 
Could somebody please tell me what I do wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` operator, when used on strings, concatenates the strings instead of trying to coerce them to numbers like the `*` operator. You can use `parseInt()` to get integers instead of strings.

```
$('.button').mouseup(function()  {
    var sum = parseInt($("#field1").val()) + parseInt($("#field2").val());
    $("#result").val(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.val()` retrieves a string, and adding strings concatenates them.

Use [`parseInt(str,10)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) on the values first to convert them to base-10 integers:

```
var sum = parseInt($("#field1").val(),10)+parseInt($("#field2").val(),10);
```

If you're dealing with non-integer values, use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that javascript is interpreted the `+` operator as a string concatenation operation and not addition.  It does this because both the left and right side of `+` are string values.  To get addition you need to coerce them into `int` values

```
var left = parseInt($("#field1").val());
var right = parseInt($("#field2").val());
var sum = left + right;
```

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` returns a string, not a number. You need to wrap in `parseInt(...val(), 10);`

Answer (score 0):

The values (ie `$("#field1").val()`) that you're working with are strings unless otherwise converted.

The `+` operator is a concatenate operator when applied to strings.

Use the `Number()` function around then to convert to numerics before adding:

```
var sum = Number($("#field1").val())+Number($("#field2").val());
```

In the case of the `*` operator, I suspect that this is automatically converting to numerics, either because the `*` operator on strings is setup to do so automatically (as `*` has no logical meaning for two strings), or because your strings are being recognised as numerics, so that the `*` operator is able to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `parseInt()` call to handle pulling values for numbers.

`parseInt($('#field1').val())` for example.